# JavaScript callback or observer

Tags: javascript, callback

This is a general question about javascript. What I want to achieve but I don't know if it's possible is the following.

I want to write a javascript library that contains an object. So by using this javascript library I want to instanciate the object from another javascript file by doing:

```
myObject = new myObject();
```

I achieved that by writing a function in my javascript library:

```
function myObject() {
    //init object logic
}
```

The thing is that now I want to be able to listen to different events of that object from the javascript file where I instansciated the object before. something like:

```
myObject = new myObject();

myObject.on('connection', function(conn) {
             conn.on('data', function(data){

                    console.log("conn on data");

                });

                conn.on('error', function(data){

                    console.log("conn on error");

                });

            });
```

How can I achieve this in javascript? I was thinking about callbacks but I can't figure out the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a `EventEmitter` which you could implement this way:

```js
class EventEmitter  {
  constructor () {
    this.events = {};
  }
  on (channel, cb) {
    if (Array.isArray(this.events[channel])) {
      this.events[channel].push(cb);
    } else {
      this.events[channel] = [cb];
    }
  }
  emit (channel, ...args) {
    if (Array.isArray(this.events[channel])) {
      this.events[channel].forEach(cb => cb.apply(null, args));
    }
  }
}
```

Your class can inherit from `EventEmitter`:

```js
class MyClass extends EventEmitter {
  constructor () {
    super();
    // do initialization
  }
}
```

And now, you can instantiate your class:

```js
var myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.on('event', function (a, b) {
  console.log('Event A was emitted: ', a + b); 
});
myObject.emit('event', 123, 456); // "Event A was emitted: 579"
```

Working example:

```js
class EventEmitter  {
  constructor () {
    this.events = {};
  }
  on (channel, cb) {
    if (Array.isArray(this.events[channel])) {
      this.events[channel].push(cb);
    } else {
      this.events[channel] = [cb];
    }
  }
  emit (channel, ...args) {
    if (Array.isArray(this.events[channel])) {
      this.events[channel].forEach(cb => cb.apply(null, args));
    }
  }
}

class MyClass extends EventEmitter {
  constructor () {
    super();
    // do initialization
  }
}

var myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.on('event', function (a, b) {
  console.log('Event A was emitted: ', a + b); 
});
myObject.emit('event', 123, 456); // "Event A was emitted: 579"
```

Note that I used a few new features, for example the spread operator (`...`) and the new `class` syntax. Of course, you can also achieve the same using the old `function` and `prototype` way.

In your code, you have the line

```js
myObject = new myObject();
```

Don't do that. You assign the new instance to the variable that contains the constructor, losing access to that constructor.

NodeJS has its own [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) class. You can access it using:

```js
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
```

Answer (score 1):

//library

```
      function myObject() {
         //init object logic
      }

      myObject.prototype.attach=function(eventType,callBack){
          //default event
          document.addEventListener(eventType,callBack);
           ......

            //custom event code
            var event = new Event('connection');

            // Listen for the event.
            document.addEventListener('connection', function (e) { ... }, false);

      }
```

//userFile

```
      myObject = new myObject();

      myObject.attach("click",clikeMe);
      function clickMe(eventObject){
        .......
        ......
       }
```

// to dispatch custom event

```
        document.dispatchEvent(event)
```

Comment: And how do you dispatch the event?

Comment: @PeterMader I just given overview how to add event listener for default events,we can use custom create event code to add user defined events which goes inside attach function

Comment: Still, you could provide how to dispatch the event with your approach. Also, you don't know if the OP uses client-side JavaScript or an environment where `document` is not available.